# Having trouble installing .Net on aarch64 ubuntumate, 22.04 (raspberrypi 400)

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, arm64

I've been trying to install the .NET SDK using Snap, binaries, Docker and tarballs. The Docker CLI returned what looked like a perfect download, same for Snapcraft. Upon running dotnet, I am met with this message: "/snap/dotnet-sdk/79/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner: 3: exec: /snap/dotnet-sdk/79/dotnet: not found". A .Net folder was created inside my snap folder, along with a folder in  my downloads, called "dotnet-core-b43c655".